# Javascript Disabled - Use Different stylesheet?

Tags: css, javascript

I have a jquery slider that works great with a few pictures.  The client would like the pictures to stack in a downward fashion when JS is turned off.  The problem is I have a title for each picture that is a link to an article.  The titles for each picture when JS is turned off is now only at the bottom picture.

Is there some way to style a page only when JS is turned off? So, Javascript is disabled, use this style for this section??

Comment: This is tough, because `<noscript>` doesn't work in the `head` in many browsers. Hmmm....

Comment: `<noscript>` is a nasty binary solution designed only to add content to the body element and that falls over if a script is blocked (or times out, or whatever) in a browser that otherwise has JS turned on.

Comment: Don't know where you get that definintion for <noscript>. It's the best solution here make the javascript view the default and include a stylesheet enclosed in a <noscript> tag which will then be applied which javascript is turned off, this works on ALL browser including IE 6 and it is valid HTML 5

Comment: @davidbuttar — Practical experience. It's a rubbish solution for anything. Cheap, but nasty.

Comment: @david dorward, you'll need to provide an example where it would cause a negative? I think it's the ideal solution, most users have javascript on so the site should be designed for them by default. Otherwise the non-js version is rendered first and there is often a jump when js kicks in and applies its styles. Now that really is nasty and a bad user experience.

Comment: @davidbuttar — I did, two examples in fact. And if you get a jump, then you've timed the execution of the JS to add the class names badly.

Comment: You have to wait until the DOM has loaded to manipulate elements, by which time the browser will be displaying the non-js version, nothing to do with bad timing. I don't see why the majority should have to suffer judderly loading pages because of a small minority blocking scripts. As for scripts timing out, I can't remember the last time that happened, it's really not a serious problem for MOST users.

Comment: You don't have to wait until the *whole* DOM has loaded. Only the bit you want to manipulate. Scripts timing out are quite a common problem for *lots* of users (e.g. those on 3G).

Answer (score 5):

Use progressive enhancement instead. It is a safer approach.

1. Write HTML that works by itself
2. Write CSS to style it nicely
3. Write JavaScript and CSS to make it interactive in the way you want

   - You can add the CSS with JS by appending a new `<link>` element
   - You can cause CSS in the preexisting stylesheet to start applying to the elements by adding a class name to their container.

Comment: I follow graceful degradation as there are only a small percentage of people who don't have/disabled js. For them, just make it look good. Due to this reason, I follow Daniel's Solution.

Comment: A small percentages of a large number is a large number … and Daniel's solution is just an example of the generic steps I describe.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use javascript to *add* additional CSS either by jQuery's `addClass` or loading up a new `style` or `link` tag?

Example using jQuery:

```
$('body').addClass("scriptEnabled");
```

CSS:

```
#mysection {
   color: red;
}

body.scriptEnabled #mySection {
   color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution to adding a class to the body is to document.write the other stylesheet into the page.